# Almacenar cantidad de horas en Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, trigger

tengo dos tablas (Piloto y Vuelo).

```
CREATE TABLE PILOTO
(
ID_PILOTO          VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
CÓDIGO_PILOTO      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMER_NOMBRE      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMER_APELLIDO    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
HORAS_VUELO        DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE VUELO 
(
ID_VUELO                VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
FECHA                   DATE NOT NULL,
HORA_ENCENDIDO          DATE NOT NULL,
HORA_APAGADO            DATE NOT NULL,
DURACION_VUELO          DATE NOT NULL,
CANTIDAD_ATERRIZAJES    INTEGER NOT NULL,
AEROPUERTO_ID_SALIDA    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
AEROPUERTO_ID_LLEGADA   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Lo que pretendo es que en el campo HORAS_VUELO de la tabla Piloto, se vaya almacenando la cantidad de horas de vuelo de cada piloto, en función de la duración de los vuelos que haga. Intenté colocar estos campos como DATE(ya que no hay forma de hacer un tratamiento directo con las horas en Oracle).

Para esto creé un Trigger que hiciera la suma de horas, pero evidentemente me arroja error ya que no se pueden sumar dos Date.

¿Qué tipo de dato debería ser el campo HORAS_VUELO para que se le puedan ir sumando horas?

De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

EDITO: La idea es poder almacenar la suma de las horas en formato 11:30 u 11.5

Comment: Depende de si solamente vas a almacenar datos enteros, es decir, solamente vas a contar horas exactas o si por otro lado vas a guardar algo como 1.5 horas o 01:30 horas, como veras, depende mucho de como hayas pensado enviar el dato a la DB. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Josue, olvidé colocarlo en la pregunta. Realmente puede ser en ambos formatos, sería bueno en 11:30, pero me vale también tipo 11.5. Estuve pensando en manejarlo todo como INTEGER, y en el código hacer las conversiones pertinentes.

Answer (score 1):

Hice un par de pruebas para poder hacerte una propuesta que fuese viable o por lo menos eso me parece, lo primero que te recomiendo es que utilices `NUMERIC(18,2)` para el campo `HORAS_VUELO` de la tabla `PILOTO`, esto guardara las horas en formato decimal (solamente debes multiplicar los decimales *60 para saber a cuántos minutos equivale), además debido a que ya tienes en la tabla `VUELO` la duración del mismo, puedes utilizar el campo para actualizar las horas de vuelo de cada piloto, para ello añadí el `ID_PILOTO` también a la tabla `VUELO`, en mi ejemplo calcule el valor de la duración en base a las fechas y horas de `HORA_ENCENDIDO` y `HORA_APAGADO` para ello cambie los tipos a `TIMESTAMP` y aunque no es necesario para el cálculo, yo lo dejaria por si en algún momento necesitas ese dato, sin mas, te dejo el ejemplo:

Estructura de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE PILOTO
(
ID_PILOTO          VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
CÓDIGO_PILOTO      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMER_NOMBRE      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMER_APELLIDO    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
HORAS_VUELO        NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE VUELO 
(
ID_VUELO                VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
ID_PILOTO               VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FECHA                   DATE NOT NULL,
HORA_ENCENDIDO          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
HORA_APAGADO            TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
DURACION_VUELO          NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL,
CANTIDAD_ATERRIZAJES    INTEGER NOT NULL,
AEROPUERTO_ID_SALIDA    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
AEROPUERTO_ID_LLEGADA   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
```

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=06ce0d362dcf6c5cd9167e96c8bc2463)</kbd>

Ojala sea lo que estabas buscando. Saludos.